# Trying to Restore Google Chrome Session, but what should the Session_xxxxxx and Tabs_xxxxxx files be renamed to?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, data-recovery

Pretty much title. Apparently you need to rename these files to recover your Chrome session, but what should I rename them to? I have three files in my \Sessions\ folder;

- Session_13312225469757655 (2.457 KB)
- Tabs_13312222131531014    (581   KB)
- Tabs_13312553148072816    (2.596 KB)

I have backups of these files, and I've tried putting them in the \Sessions\ folder, but it doesn't work.

Anyways, help would be appreciated

EDIT: The post association is wrong, as the associated post does not provide the answer to my question; "What should the Tabs_xxxxx and Session_xxxx files be renamed to?"